# ASP.Net , data validation should be in the controller, not the model, contrary to this tutorial example?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am following `ASP.NET MVC Music Store Tutorial by Jon Galloway Microsoft` from http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com

While setting up this fictitious music store , we have `Album.cs` as the model with these lines of code

```
public class Album
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "An Album Title is required")]
    [StringLength(160)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    //.......More code follows
```

What I find confusing is, why is the validation being done here by the `Required` attribute in the model, instead of the controller? Isn't the controller supposed to do the validation? or is that standard practice to do the validation in the model...suppposedly the tutorial is from microsoft?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I find confusing is, why is the validation being done here by the
>   Required attribute in the model, instead of the controller

Actually that's the domain model and it should have domain validation on it in order to ensure that it will stay consistent. On the other hand you should have a view model being exposed to the views on which perform view specific validation. And if this domain model will never be reused outside of this application you could rely only on the view model validation.

For example you will see many wrong examples putting view specific data annotation attributes on the domain models such as `[DisplayFormat]` and `[Display]`. All those examples are an illustration of bad design in which the domain models are used as view models.

Comment: "And if this domain model will never be reused outside of this application you could rely only on the view model validation." . this makes sense to me. The whole confusion arises when you are told to do all the validation in your ViewModel, not IN the model(when using MVVM for example) and yet you see these MVC examples where the data is being validated IN the model instead of the controller....

Answer (score 0):

You are using `DataAnnotations` in the Model that states that the `Title` field must be filled in before being posted back to the server.  In the controller you can also check `if ModelState.IsValid` however adding the `DataAnnotations` at the Model level is the correct way to implement data validation.

Answer (score 0):

we generally use Microsoft enterprise library's validation block to validate in the controller. Which enable us to add or remove validations 
easily by modifying config file.